# How to get the IP address of a user on a website (Python)

Tags: python, streamlit

I am using Streamlit for my website, and I need to find a user's IP address. So far, I can only find my IP address, but no one else's. Is there a way to get the IP address of a user?

Comment: I tried searching the StreamLit API documentation, I couldn't find anything about the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get a user's IP address just on the server side just by using Streamlit and Python. However, you could use request if you are deploying your Streamlit app on a web server like Flask. Example:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import streamlit as st

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    user_ip = request.remote_addr
    st.write(f"User's IP address: {user_ip}")
    return "Hello, Streamlit!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```